# Prevent clicking a checkbox in Uniform library

Tags: jquery, uniform, jquery-uniform

I want to /uncheck a checkbox by JS and  prevent user to /uncheck it by click.

in normal checkboxes I can use this code:

```
$('#checkbox').on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

but this code does'nt work for Uniform checkboxes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable the click event:

```
$('#checkbox').unbind('click');
```

And then handle it like you want with:

```
$('#checkbox').prop('checked',true);
$.uniform.update();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `disable` attribute

```
$('#checkbox').on('click', function(){
    $("#checkbox").attr("disabled", true);
});
```

that will disable the checkbox once its been clicked leaving it checked

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Base/eh2tm0dn/)

Comment: thanks but I want this for uniform library. anyway Razvan Dumitru answered :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use here:

```
 $('#checkbox').uniform();
 $('#checkbox').unbind('click').bind('click', function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
 });
```